# updating datetime value in Table using Postgres & Knex

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I want to update 'access token' expiration datetime into 'users' table in order to check if the access token is valid to reset password. 
So I am passing a datetime string value using moment.

But it fails to update datetime with no error message.

The 'forgotPassword' function works find without updating 'resetPasswordExpires'.

I have tried to set 'resetPasswordExpires' column type to timeStamp. It didn't work.

```
[ Front-End ]
const inOneHour = moment()
  .add(1, 'hours')
  .format('MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss');


[ users table / Database ]
table.datetime('resetPasswordExpires', { useTz: false });
```

```
  exports.forgotPassword = (req, res) => {
   const { username, email, inOneHour } = req.body;

   return knex('users')
    .where({ username, email })
    .first()
    .then(async user => {
      if (user) {
        const token = await util.getRandomToken(user);
        const mailOptions = {
          ...
        };

        return knex('users')
          .where({ username })
          .first()
          .update({
            resetPasswordToken: token,
            resetPasswordExpires: inOneHour,
          })
          .then(() => {
            sendEmail(mailOptions)
              .then(() => {
                ...
              })
              .catch(err => {
                ...
              });
          });
      }
      ...
    });
};
```

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am sure that its failing it's just that you are not catching the exception.

First add the error handler for KNEX

```
return knex('users')
          .where({ username })
          .first()
          .update({
            resetPasswordToken: token,
            resetPasswordExpires: inOneHour,
          })
          .then(() => {
            // Do your work
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            // print out the error
          });
```

Now coming to solution, the format you have for the date i.e.`.format('MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss');` is not supported by the postgres, so you wont be able to use this format.
Your current format produces output something like `July 18th 2019, 19:03:41`

**You can use `.format('MMMM DD YYYY, HH:mm:ss');`** for starters, this create date as `July 18 2019, 19:03:41`. But I would suggest you to just do `.format()` so you don't have to worry about the format each time you use it in your code.